# paper.js & Adobe Illustrator SVG : layers compatibilty

Tags: node.js, svg, layer, adobe-illustrator, paperjs

I am creating SVG files using paper.js (from node.js, with the *paper-jsdom* package), and I would like to make them as compliant as possible with Adobe Illustrator. In order to do so, I am trying to repoduce the steps described [[here]](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/project-hierarchy/#the-difference-between-them). But then, exporting into SVG using the [*exportSVG*](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#exportsvg) function, I get something quite different :

[image: Both shapes are in the same layer, but in different groups]

The layer compatibility between paper.js and AI does not seems to work anymore. So, am I missing something here ? Is it because of my version of AI (CC 2018) ? Would there be a way to bypass this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `Paper.js` SVG export was ever compatible with `Illustrator` layer model.
You say that this "does not seems to work anymore" but did you make it work with previous versions of `Paper.js`/`AI` ?
If not, I guess that you were confused by the analogy that is made in `Paper.js` documentation about their shared layer concept.
But this analogy is only made because users are used to `AI` layers and this allow them to better understand how `Paper.js` works.

From that, I was curious to see how `AI` was able to restore its layers after a SVG export, to see if there was a possible workaround in your case.
When you export your `AI` project as SVG, you can choose to "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" or not.
If you don't, the exported SVG will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="1137px" height="937px" viewBox="0 0 1137 937"
     enable-background="new 0 0 1137 937" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Calque_1_1_">
    <circle fill="#FF0000" cx="380" cy="238" r="60"/>
</g>
<g id="Calque_2">
    <circle fill="#0000FF" cx="569" cy="468" r="60"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

But if you try to load this SVG back into `AI`, you won't get 2 layers, but only one containing 2 groups (as you do with `Paper.js` exported SVG).

If you check "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities", you will get a very different result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
    ]>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;"
     xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1137px"
     height="937px"
     viewBox="0 0 1137 937" enable-background="new 0 0 1137 937"
     xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1"
                   height="1">
        <i:pgfRef xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:pgfRef>
    </foreignObject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g id="Calque_1">
            <circle fill="#FF0000" cx="380" cy="238" r="60"/>
        </g>
        <g id="Calque_2">
            <circle fill="#0000FF" cx="569" cy="468" r="60"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</switch>
    <i:pgf id="adobe_illustrator_pgf">
    <![CDATA[
    ...(huge data skipped)
    ]]>
</i:pgf>
</svg>
```

This time, if you load this back into `AI`, you will get your layers, as expected.
The difference resides in all the meta data that `AI` adds to the SVG in order to load it back, and most importantly, the `<i:pgf id="adobe_illustrator_pgf">` element.
There is a [thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/179679) discussing about the same kind of problem in `Inskape` context and it seems that this crucial data is a kind of binary data that only `AI` can read and write.

So as a final word, unfortunately, I don't think that there is a chance that you or `Paper.js` can make a SVG file that maps to `AI` internal layers model.